# Fabric - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'fabric_server'@'%''

Tags: mysql

I am finding the use of fabric to be tottalyh unstable.  Here is what I do and the below is the result:

mysqlfabric group add druid 192.34.59.181:3306
mysqlfabric group add druid 192.34.56.66:3306
mysqlfabric group promote druid

Why is fabric so difficult?  the fabric users were created on all servers.

```
                                uuid is_alive    status is_not_running is_not_configured io_not_running sql_not_running io_error                                                                                                                                                                                                                    sql_error
------------------------------------ -------- --------- -------------- ----------------- -------------- --------------- -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c5c0345b-c101-11e5-a6eb-04019dd77301        1   PRIMARY              0                 0              0               0    False                                                                                                                                                                                                                        False
fb6b2f9d-c0bf-11e5-ac4f-04019da86e01        1 SECONDARY              0                 0              0               1    False Error 'Operation CREATE USER failed for 'fabric_server'@'%'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE USER 'fabric_server'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*0C21C48C1D8B7C42A8155CC993649AB7478D6102''

issue
-----


root@fabric-forex-do-development-ny-druid-20160122035236:~# mysqlfabric group lookup_servers druid
Fabric UUID:  5ca1ab1e-a007-feed-f00d-cab3fe13249e
Time-To-Live: 1

                         server_uuid            address    status       mode weight
------------------------------------ ------------------ --------- ---------- ------
c5c0345b-c101-11e5-a6eb-04019dd77301  192.34.56.66:3306   PRIMARY READ_WRITE    1.0
fb6b2f9d-c0bf-11e5-ac4f-04019da86e01 192.34.59.181:3306 SECONDARY  READ_ONLY    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute on your secondary:

mysql> drop user 'fabric_server'@'%';

mysql> stop slave;

mysql> start slave;

Worked for me.

Best Rgds,
Jeferson Santana
DBA